# Load list items on demand

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I would like to load a list of messages on demand. 
I show 20 messages on my listview and when the user scrolls on top of list there is a button to load more 20 messages. 
Like whatsapp, when user clicks on the button, more messages are loaded above and the user can scroll 20 more messages.

I have tried to make it with Loaders, every time the button is clicked I publish an event that load messages on the adapter. 
However when the adapter is releoaded with new itens the focus goes to end of list.

I have tried to set the focus to the right positon, but the Loader's events reload the adapter and the focus come back to end of list.

The only solution I found was to set the focus after a time, but the user can see the list going to end and coming back to the right postion.

How can I load messages on demand like Whats app?

Comment: is it solved?if solved please help me,i am also same requirement.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have to add only 20 objects in your ArrayList and add HeaderView in your list adapter .On click on headerView .It will load more 20 items in your list adapter . and call notifyDataSetChange(); afterwards.